# Generating a number sequence using Perl

Tags: perl

I am trying to generate a number sequence as below using Perl:

```
1
2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9 10
11 .. n
```

where n is an user input.

So I came up with the below logic which looks pretty novice. How can I make it better?

```
$a   = <STDIN>;
$ln  = 1;
$val = 1;
$itr = 1;

do {
    do {
        if ($val <= $a) {
            print "$val\t";
        } else {
            print "\n";
            exit;
        }
        $val++;
        $itr++;
    } while($itr <= $ln);
    $ln++;
    $itr = 1;
    print "\n";
} while ($a > 0);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a few pointers for you:

- Always include [`use strict;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) and [`use warnings;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html) in *every* Perl script.
- Don't forget to [`chomp`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) your input pulled from `STDIN`.
- Avoid using  a `do BLOCK` with a statement modifier.  Instead always use a [`while`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/while.html) or a [`for`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/for.html) loop.
- Avoid using `$a` or `$b` as variable names as they are reserved for [`sort`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html).

Applying these changes, and also making it so that we use math to determine if we're at the end of a line gives the following script:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

chomp(my $number = <STDIN>);

my $line = 1;

for my $iter (1 .. $number) {
    if ($iter == $line * ($line + 1) / 2 || $iter == $number) {
        print "$iter\n";
        $line++;
    } else {
        print "$iter\t";
    }
}
```

Outputs (with the input of 17):

```
17
1
2       3
4       5       6
7       8       9       10
11      12      13      14      15
16      17
```

#### Alternative using the [quadratic formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula)

It's also possible to get fancy and achieve the same output using a single statement:

```
my $number = 17;

for (1 .. $number) {
    print $_, ((sqrt(8 * $_ + 1) - 1) / 2) !~ /\./ || $_ == $number ? "\n" : "\t";
}
```

Comment: Oh Wow !! Thanks a lot guys. And I apologize for the missing details and not being compliant. Will make sure this never happens.

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;

my $number = 1;
print "Enter a number: ";
my $n = <STDIN>;


for ( my $i = 0; $i < $n ; $i++)
{
  for (my $j = 0; $j < $i ; $j++)
  {
    while ($number<=$n)
    {
      print "$number ";
      $number++;
      last;
    }
  }

  if ( $number <= $n)
  {
    print "\n";
  }
}
```

---

Nice edit.  Your code works, but I'd like to take the nonstandard approach of suggesting some improvements within your answer.

This not the typical approach, and we can (and probably should) edit out this section after you've had a chance to consider the info.  However, since you're someone who is just starting the process of helping out other programmers, I'd like to make some special effort:

- Always include both `use strict;` and `use warnings;` in *every* Perl script.

This is the the #1 tip that we can share with any beginning Perl programmer, and a fair number of intermediate programmers too.  Anytime a new programmer doesn't use one of these pragmas, it's a good idea to point it out to them first thing.  This is most common with new SO users with less than 10 reputation.  It's also a good idea to always model the usage of these pragmas in code that we demonstrate even if it isn't vital to the functionality of an example.

- Study [`perlstyle`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlstyle.html) for suggested formatting tips for Perl code.

Everyone is entitled to have their own style of course, but you'll find that most Perl coders have adopted certain standards for spacing.  This isn't a rule, just a suggestion.  But you will notice that I will have changed the formatting in my fine tuning of your code.

- Pick meaningful variable names.

Never use single letter variable names.  This isn't just for the benefit of other coders, it's also for your own benefit 6 months from now.  It's always worthwhile to give a variable a meaningful name as that's the #1 way you can make your code self-documenting.

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl
    use strict;
    use warnings;

    print "Enter a number: ";
    my $max = <STDIN>;

    my $number = 1;

    for ( my $row = 0; $row < $max ; $row++) {
        for (my $col = 0; $col < $row ; $col++) {
            while ($number <= $max) {
                print "$number ";
                $number++;
                last;
            }
        }

        if ( $number <= $max) {
            print "\n";
        }
    }
```

Anytime that you feel tempted to use a basic variable name, use the default variable `$_` instead.

```
    for (MIN .. MAX) {
```

If `$_` won't work for whatever reason, then you should be using a meaningful variable name.

- Always [`chomp`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) input from `<STDIN>`

Your script will work fine regardless in this particular case.  However, there are a fair number of questions that get posted on this site because some beginner didn't `chomp` their input and then they attempted to either use the filename in an `open` statement or the variable in a comparison.

To avoid these subtle bugs and just to model good habits, always aim to demonstrate `chomp`ing input even if it's not strictly necessary.

```
    chomp(my $max = <STDIN>);
```

- Instead of a C-style for loop, I'd recommend using counting loops.

Additionally, since you're just counting, I'd recommend starting from 1 and ending at your maximum number:

```
    for my $row ( 1 .. $max ) {
        for my $col ( 1 .. $row ) {
```

- Your use of a `while (COND) {...; last;}` is synonymous with a simple `if` statement:

  ```
            if ($number <= $max) {
                print "$number ";
                $number++;
            }
  ```
- What are you actually iterating on?

If you think about it, you're actually trying to iterate on the `$number` variable.  The variables `$row` and `$col` are actually state variables that are used for formatting.  It therefore makes sense to completely invert your logic to the following:

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl
    use strict;
    use warnings;

    print "Enter a number: ";
    chomp( my $max = <STDIN> );

    my $row = 1;
    my $col = 1;

    for my $number ( 1 .. $max ) {
        if ($col == $row || $number == $max) {
            $row++;
            $col = 1;
            print "$number\n";
        } else {
            $col++;
            print "$number ";
        }
    }
```

This final version has the benefit of not needlessly looping through lines that aren't going to be printed.  It also has a unsurprising resemblance to my first solution, except that this contains two state variables instead of just 1 in mine.

Overall, I think this final solution might actually be a better recommendation for a beginner programmer which this OP is, so I shall vote up this answer.  Please feel free to remove everything but the final answer after you've read these comments.

Note: I won't ever edit a question like this again.  Typically the practice is just to edit the question and provide an explanation in the edit summary.  However, I had a number of things I wanted to share to hopefully assist you in the future.  Welcome to SO and thanks for helping out others too.

Comment: Yes, but the user explicitly starts with external input.  Say `my $number = 17`, could you adjust your solution to print the output properly?

Comment: Nice edit, I've added a lot of comments to your new version, and a cleaned up final version.  Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

To answer the literal title of the original question, or to generate a finite sequence of integers in Perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict; use warnings;
use Data::Dumper qw(Dumper);
my @monthn = (1..12);
print Dumper \@monthn;
```

And this produces

```
$VAR1 = [
          1,
          2,
          3,
          4,
          5,
          6,
          7,
          8,
          9,
          10,
          11,
          12
        ];
```